# Email Authentication in Angular 6

Tags: angular

How to do email authentication in angular 6 like stack overflow ?

For example:  when user click on signup button ,he will get a mail to  verify   email.After clicking on that link he will be able to move to  the home page.please help me.

Comment: You can't do it only with Angular. You will need some backend server. NodeJs if you prefer to stick with Javascript, Django for python, or any other. Your Angular application will call your backend, and the backend will do the job of storing users, creating notifications etc. (flagged this question as too broad).

Comment: when i am clicking on register button getting token from API as a response but don't know how to do it

Comment: you have to clarify your question, what you are using, which modules, with samples from you code, with exact errors on what is the problem, see examples of other well received questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53222039/retrieving-token-from-email-angular-6

Comment: also you could refer following article : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52512718/how-to-redirect-to-angular-6-page-when-user-click-on-account-activation-in-email

Comment: Thank you very much Joseph by sharing this link .I  got the solution @ Joel Joseph